# Converting list to np array of some definite size

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have an `np array` like this  `[366, 731, 48813, 151, 5607, 45568, 24681, 1642, 48814]`
( I know its a list , just eg)
How can I convert it into an `np array` of some max size , where the later bits are just zeroes ?
 thing is that I have lists like these which I want to use `np.append()`

```
[366, 731, 48813, 151, 5607, 45568, 24681, 1642, 48814]
[]
[2325, 148, 211, 37, 24203, 12, 7332, 1415, 196, 141, 41, 4598, 29, 4147, 2231, 8954, 8938, 44, 27993, 5714, 10282, 7858, 785, 21925, 26456, 22217, 5212, 4017]
[]
[8932, 48815, 1415, 3430, 29, 180, 37, 4425, 2983, 639, 25, 633, 9167, 6154, 29, 1720, 577, 34017, 48816]
[]
```

which you can see are of varying sizes, and ignore the empty lists

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  It's not a clone of list append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one efficient way with `numpy` which avoids `append`:

```
def sizer(arr, n):
    out = np.zeros(n)
    out[:len(arr)] = arr
    return out

A = [366, 731, 48813, 151, 5607, 45568, 24681, 1642, 48814]

sizer(np.array(A), 14)

# array([   366.,    731.,  48813.,    151.,   5607.,  45568.,  24681.,
#          1642.,  48814.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.])
```

To stack multiple arrays into one array:

```
A = [366, 731, 48813, 151, 5607, 45568, 24681, 1642, 48814]
B = [23, 452, 53, 23412, 3124, 1234]
C = [452, 4654, 5476, 547654, 7654, 567, 324, 5436]
D = []

lst = [A, B, C, D]

np.vstack(sizer(np.array(i), max(map(len, lst))) for i in lst if i)
```

**Explanation**

- Use generator expression to construct iterable of arrays from `lst`.
- `max(map(len, lst))` calculates the maximum list size in `lst`.
- `sizer()` resizes each array to this maximum size.
- `np.vstack` stacks an iterable vertically into a `numpy` array.
- `if i` makes sure you only include non-empty lists.

**Result**

```
array([[  3.66000000e+02,   7.31000000e+02,   4.88130000e+04,
          1.51000000e+02,   5.60700000e+03,   4.55680000e+04,
          2.46810000e+04,   1.64200000e+03,   4.88140000e+04],
       [  2.30000000e+01,   4.52000000e+02,   5.30000000e+01,
          2.34120000e+04,   3.12400000e+03,   1.23400000e+03,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  4.52000000e+02,   4.65400000e+03,   5.47600000e+03,
          5.47654000e+05,   7.65400000e+03,   5.67000000e+02,
          3.24000000e+02,   5.43600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: i mean , i want to create a big matrix with many rows, so i'll need to use append , but yeah , what you wrote , i'll have to use that only for appending, thanks

Comment: nope, too complicated for my level of understanding , the function is pretty and easy, i'll just keep on appending after creating a list with filled zeros , since that more simple for me to understand

Comment: @ShubhamDebnath, apologies - i have now added an explanation.